# Python tkinter : How to change my file icon?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't want the python icon I want to change my icon 
So,how to change my executable file icon 
I tried this

```
from tkinter import *
import os
top=Tk()
os.file.icon('pyt.ico')
top.mainloop()
```

but it is showing error

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong. However:

```
top.wm_iconbitmap('path_to_youricon.ico')
```